# Adobe after effects edit templates

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I'm struggling to edit the template of an intro. I'm quite new to Adobe After Effects, ideally I want to change the logo and text. I've managed to change the text underneath the logo, but not the logo itself. I tried to remove the logo, but it says "Are you sure, this logo is used in 10 other compositions."

Any suggestions?

https://motionarray.com/after-effects-templates/glitch-logo-476737/

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Sorry, but video editing is [off-topic](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. Try Video Production Stack Exchange instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the “project menu to your left, right click on “m-hexagon-v1.png” then click “replace footage” and select your .PNG file from the select file dialogue pop-up menu.